# How to use "class table inheritance" in Doctrine 2 with XML mapping

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, class-table-inheritance

I'm trying to use the "class table inheritance feature" of Doctrine 2 with XML Mapping (Symfony 2 PR 7).

XML definition of the XML superclass CatalogProduct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                          http://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="MyApp\CatalogBundle\Entity\CatalogProduct" table="catalog_product" inheritance-type="JOINED">
        <discriminator-column name="discr" type="string" />
        <discriminator-map>
            <discriminator-mapping value="book" class="MyApp\CatalogBundle\Entity\CatalogBook" />
        </discriminator-map>
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
            <sequence-generator sequence-name="tablename_seq" allocation-size="100" initial-value="1" />
        </id>
        <field name="name" column="name" type="string" length="50" nullable="true" unique="false" />
        <field name="isPublic" column="is_public" type="boolean" />        
    </entity>    
</doctrine-mapping>
```

XML definition of the XML superclass CatalogBook, that should extend CatalogProduct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                          http://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="MyApp\CatalogBundle\Entity\CatalogBook" table="catalog_book">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
            <sequence-generator sequence-name="tablename_seq" allocation-size="100" initial-value="1" />
        </id>
        <field name="author_name" column="author_name" type="string" length="50" nullable="true" unique="false" />
    </entity>    
</doctrine-mapping>
```

./php app/console doctrine:generate:entities "CatalogBundle"

works fine (entities generatetd), but CatalogBook turns out to be a "simple" class, not extending CatalogProduct.

```
$book = new CatalogBook();
$book->setAuthorName('some author');
$book->setName('some book name');
```

leads to an exception:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyApp\CatalogBundle\Entity\CatalogBook::setName()
```

I guess, I'm missing something in the XML, that tells the CatalogBook Entity to extend CatalogProduct. But I coudln't find anything in the Doctrine 2 Documentation or on Google that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Generate entities does not generate the inheritance hierachy for you, because that is semantically not possible. You have to do it yourself after invoking doctrine:generate:entities.